# API call from post trigger of DocumentDB

Tags: rest, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I need to make an API call from post trigger of Azure DocumentDB. 
I tried calling external APIs - but found that such calls are blocked in DocumentDB. If I host an API on Azure's same account will that API is allowed to be called from the post trigger ? If not what can be the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side code runs in a sandboxed environment and cannot make external calls. You can, instead, make the same call from your client after your request is acknowledged by the service (indicating your post-trigger succeeded/failed).

Answer (score 1):

DocumentDB now supports a private preview of server side change feed. Using this model you can pull down all the changes from a DocumentDB collection and execute custom logic to perform desired post processing like invoking web services.

Please email askdocdb at Microsoft dot com if you want to learn more about this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In server-side scripts you can use all JavaScript functionality and CRUD/Query API for DocumentDB. Other "hosting" API is not exposed. For instance, JavaScript by itself doesn't have built-in support for file system or web API, functionality like needs to be provided by host (IE, cscript, etc). DocumentDB doesn't provide additional API other than CRUD/Query API.